# Is Content-Disposition required for a multipart/form-data HTTP POST?

Tags: http, post, http-post, multipart, content-disposition

What if I'm just sending an array of images in no particular order, i.e., the `name` field doesn't matter, and I just want the server to determine the `filename` arbitrarily?

Must I send `Content-Disposition` for each file?

Answer (score 0):

According to [RFC2183](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2183), "Content-Disposition is an optional header field."

Comment: Though not supplying a Content-Disposition might confuse the software at the other end.